# Are "atraente" and "atrativo" always interchangeable?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, adjetivos

As far back as I can remember, I've always used **"atraente" as an adjective** ("Ela é uma mulher muito atraente.") **and "atrativo" as a noun** ("O bônus semestral é um atrativo a mais."). Since the end of the twentieth century, however, I've noticed people often using "atrativo" as an adjective

- "Eles oferecem um salário muito atrativo."
- "Paris é uma das cidades mais atrativas que conheço."

I was puzzled and looked the word up in my Aurelio.  I found it can really be an adjective but I'm not convinced both adjectives are always interchangeable.  I still find it awkward to hear/say:

> - **"Que mulher atrativa!"**
> - **"Esse vestido te deixa muito atrativa."**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O dicionário Aulete digital permite uma distinção clara entre [***atraente***](http://www.aulete.com.br/atraente), que inclui o significado de bonito, vistoso, e [***atrativo***](http://www.aulete.com.br/atrativo), que não inclui esse significado. O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa apresenta um quadro um pouco menos claro:

> ***Atrativo***
> (1) Que tem a propriedade de fazer vir até si, de puxar para si; que atrai. *Esfera atrativa*. (2) Que cativa, seduz; que inspira simpatia, afeição.
> (3) Que faz aderir a qualquer coisas; que alicia. *Tentava convencê-la com propostas atrativas.*
>
> ***Atraente***
> (1) Que agrada fisicamente, cativa, seduz; que tem encanto, graciosidade.
> (2) Que desperta interesse. = Aliciante, atrativo.
> (3) Que é agradável, convidativo, acolhedor. *Decoração atraente.*

*Atraente (2)* e *atrativo (3)* são sinónimos e coincidem com definições do Aulete. Já *atrativo (2)*, não incluído no Aulete, se aproxima mais de *atraente (1) e (3)*. A diferença é que *atraente (1)* tem mais a ver com ser vistoso. *Atrativo* aparece com o significado (2) em várias obras de ficção. Por exemplo:

> [Acerca da Sofia] Contudo, não podia negar que era mui *atrativa* e que valsava perfeitamente. ([Machado de Assis](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machado_de_Assis), [*Quincas Borba*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quincas_Borba), 1891.)
>
> Achava docemente *atrativa* a tristeza eterna de Emília. ([Raul Pompeia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raul_Pompeia), *As Joias da Família*, 1882.)
>
> [N]ão reparavam que no íntimo do maldito se escondia a serpente da crueldade, e debaixo da mais *atractiva* das afabilidades. ([Mário Cláulio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1rio_Cl%C3%A1udio), *Peregrinação de Barnabé das Índias*, 1998.)
>
> De entre os lugares *atractivos* que ali surgiram, aconteceu-me ir algumas vezes a um pub, dirigido por dois ingleses, barzinho de tons escuros... ([Urbano Tavares Rodrigues](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbano_Tavares_Rodrigues), *Dias Coloridos*, conto incluído em título que não consegui identificar, possivelmente 1952-2008.)

Isto foi uma descoberta para mim. Eu usaria atraente em qualquer dos exemplos anteriores. E o que é curioso é que, tal como registado neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), o adjetivo *atrativo*, em qualquer dos seus significados, parece desaparecer durante a maior parte do século XX (as duas últimas citações são exemplos únicos) enquanto *atraente* e o substantivo *atrativo* estão sempre presentes. Portanto a impressão do Centaurus, que coincide com a minha, tem razão de ser. Mas ao que parece, Machado de Assis não levantaria uma sobrancelha se ouvisse alguém dizer *mulher muito atrativa*.

Comment: A real treatise on the subject.  Thank you!

Comment: Do the Portuguese still write "atrativo" with a "c" before the "t"?  If not, why keep the "c" in "facto" but not in "atrativo"?

Comment: We actually pronounce the "c" in facto, but not in atrativo.

Comment: Pode ser de interés as origens etimológicas das palavras.  Ambas, obviamente, vêm do verbo *atrair*.  O sufixo *-nte* forma o antigo particípio ativo e significa(va) «que [verbo]», neste caso, algo atraente é algo «que atrai».  O sufixo *-ivo* sói significar «que tem ou possui a capacidade de [verbo]», é dizer, algo atrativo é  algo «que pode atrair».

Comment: Parece-me no entanto que no português é *atrativo* e não *atraente* a palavra que está na mente dos falantes mais próxima de *atrair*. Repara nas próprias definições acima.

Answer (score 4):

De facto, ambas podem ser adjetivos sinónimos. O Aulete Digital lista para [atraente](http://www.aulete.com.br/atraente):

> 2. Que desperta o interesse (proposta *atraente*).

E para [atrativo](http://www.aulete.com.br/atrativo):

> 2. Que atrai, que desperta interesse (preço *atrativo*); ATRAENTE

No entanto, nas frases que dás como exemplo no fim, *atraente* é de facto a única palavra possível. Este é o sentido 1. do Aulete:

> 1. Que atrai ou seduz pela beleza, pelo charme (rapaz *atraente*); BONITO; FORMOSO; VISTOSO